# Previously working Jupyter Notebook cells now crash

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, kernel, pipenv

**My environment: pipenv> jupyter notebook> python3**

Currently running a .merge() on a dataset in a cell that had previously run successfully, but it no longer running. The first merge works, but the second is problematic (labeled `full_df` below).

When checking my Mac's Activity Monitory, it appears this code is taking up the most memory.

When I interrupt the kernel, I receive an error included below.

How may I run this code once again? Example code included below.

1) I've tried shutting down my kernel completely which relieves my memory.
2) I've considered a try/except but not entirely sure if it will allow an output and will, instead, adjust the error output.
3) Tried running in Spyder but don't believe that would solve anything--just desperate.

```
df1 = pd.merge(df_ab, df_cd, left_on='ab_id', right_on='cd_id', how='left')

full_df = pd.merge(df1, df_ef, left_on='df1_id', right_on='ef_id', how='left')
```

Kernel either remains busy when I leave the cell running
OR
If I shutdown the kernel in either Spyder or Jupyter Notebook, reopen, run the cell and then interrupt, I receive the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-12-ac995c16c7cc>", line 1, in <module>
    full_df = pd.merge(df1, df_ef, left_on='df1_id', right_on='ef_id', how='left')

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 48, in merge
    return op.get_result()

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 560, in get_result
    concat_axis=0, copy=self.copy)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 2061, in concatenate_block_managers
    concatenate_join_units(join_units, concat_axis, copy=copy),

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/concat.py", line 242, in concatenate_join_units
    for ju in join_units]

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/concat.py", line 242, in <listcomp>
    for ju in join_units]

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/concat.py", line 225, in get_reindexed_values
    fill_value=fill_value)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 1651, in take_nd
    out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype)

KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: what are the sizes of your DataFrames?

Comment: What I’m joining in the above example is 22 columns and 2,000 rows.

Comment: can you try running it with `full_df = pd.merge(df1, df_ef.head(10), left_on='df1_id', right_on='ef_id', how='left')`, just to make sure that memory is the only issue?

Comment: This works and after a few minutes, I ran it without .head() and it's running again. Wondering what safety-net I could put in place to handle this issue. I'm still not exactly sure why that particular cell runs sometimes and doesn't run other times.

Comment: maybe some memory issue from the other open apps. You can place this merge inside a function and then check `%memit function_name(10)` and see how much memory it is using.